# Need advice on code optimization

Tags: java, string, optimization, substring

I am trying to generate the subsequences of two input string but my code is taking long to produce output.Just need advice for optimizing the given code.Below is the code

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



class Subsequences {

       public static void combinations(String suffix,String prefix,List seq){
        if(prefix.length()<0)return;
//        System.out.println(suffix);
        seq.add(suffix);
        for(int i=0;i<prefix.length();i++)
         combinations(suffix+prefix.charAt(i),prefix.substring(i+1,prefix.length()),seq);
    }

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        List seq1=new ArrayList();
        List seq2=new ArrayList();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        combinations("",br.readLine(),seq1);
        combinations("",br.readLine(),seq2);
        seq1.retainAll(seq2);
        if(seq1.size()>1){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }
        seq1.clear();
        seq2.clear();
        }


    }
}
```

Herein I am generating all the substrings of a string using recursion and storing all of these into arraylist.Then using retainAll I compare any common element between then.I currently takes 1.9 sec to run.Need to do it under 1 sec.

Comment: Too long to *compile*?

Comment: Mostly optimization is related to executation in runtime. What do you mean by compile time performance

Comment: Sorry....not complile...I will change the description....but the code takes more than 1 sec to produce output...i need to decrease that.

Comment: `retainAll()` is slow on lists, and you probably want unique results anyway. Use HashSet<String> instead of List. And don't use raw types.

Comment: @JBNizet...thanks for the answer...so you mean to say i replace all the references of list with map?

Comment: Did I ever talk about maps? I talked about HashSet.

Comment: OOps mistook it as hashMap...thanks...:)

Comment: Thanks,...JBNizet...set considerable improved the performance....reduced the time by half...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean it is taking too long to run not compile the program. I also assume you need to CPU profile the code to really know what the problem is. I suggest you do this before making any changes. Eg start with visual vm or even use flight recorder.

Most likely most of the time is spent in the method `combinations` which you haven't shown.

However for this sort of problem, one issue is the assumption that creating objects is free when it can be 90-99% of the time spent. I suggest you also do a memory profile and try to reduce the number of objects you create.

Only after tuning memory and cpu usage as much as possible, you might consider using multiple threads.

Comment: Hi peter...really thankful for your answer...but I am not used to memory management...can you please suggest me some references to start with...looking at your answer I would definately like to move ahead with this.Also I have updated my code now.

Comment: @Nilesh I suggest you google profiling with visual vm. It is to the memory management that is the problem but the work which goes into creating objects.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what your `combinations` method does, but it definitely isn't finding substrings.  Using a variable named `prefix` to hold a suffix and a variable `suffix` to hold a prefix is a great way to make your code hard to decipher.  You also reference a separate `combinations` method with 5 parameters that isn't present in your class.

Your performance problem could be due to using a `List` where you should be using a `Set`.  Replace `ArrayList` with `HashSet` and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @Nilesh Have you tried using a `Set` instead of `List` as I suggested?